# How can I display which cores are being used by a specific process?

Tags: rhel, cpu-usage

I'm running redHat 7.8 and have 4 CPUs with 8 cores each.

Let's say I have a running process with a PID of 111.
Is there a way I can display which specific cores that process is using and how much memory they're consuming?

`top` seems to provide too general an overview that doesn't specify how many cores are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ps`:

```
ps -o psr,drs -p 111
```

The `-o` flag enables you to specify the output format -- here, the values to display.  The `-p` flag enables you to specify the process ID(s) in which you're interested.

From `man ps`, the output fields of interest:

```
psr        PSR        processor that process is currently assigned to
drs        DRS        data resident size, the amount of physical memory
                      devoted to other than executable code
```